# Best way to redirect user to login URL in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have numerous pages that require my users to be logged in when accessing them.

I've remapped my login page to mysite.com/login. So, currently for any page that requires user to be logged in, I would redirect them using the below.

```
//If user is not logged in...
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); 
}
```

My question is, is the above good enough to ensure non-logged in users will **always be redirected** and not causing "too many redirect" errors.

Comment: depends on where you want to put this code - If you put it in a template used for private posts, then yeah, that should be enough IMO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 examples please check you can add on function.php file

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_non_logged_users_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() && is_page('add page slug or ID here') && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] != '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/' ); 
    exit;
   }
}
```

Put this in functions.php file and change the page ID or slug and the redirect url.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( is_page('slug') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {

wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.dev/your-page/', 301 ); 
  exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it important to have "exit" at the end? IF so, why?

Comment: WordPress has provided two functions for this:

wp_redirect

and

wp_safe_redirect

And here's what WordPress recommends:

Note: wp_redirect() and wp_safe_redirect() do not exit automatically, and should almost always be followed by a call to exit;